# Rails: Private RSS feed with Devise — common practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rss, devise

I would like to provide a (auto discoverable) link to a private RSS feed in a Rails application. Devise is used for authentication otherwise.

What's recommended and/or commonly used for protection of the feed in this case?

How I see it I could

- use a token for the user, append it to the link as parameter and identify the user like this,
- or I could use HTTP Basic Auth, which — correct me if I'm wrong — would force me to print user name and password onto the page in order to make link clickable, since not all RSS feed readers can deal with the authentication?

Anyone have to deal with this before and care to make a recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

Make User model token authenticate-able:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.recoverable
      t.trackable
      t.encryptable
      t.string :login
      t.string :name
      t.token_authenticatable

      t.timestamps
    end
...
end
```

Then turn on basic auth but only by token (in Devise initializer)

```
  # Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
  # config.http_authenticatable = false
  config.http_authenticatable = [:token]
```

Then render the rss link as a basic auth link using the value for @user.authentication_token as the user and password elements of the basic auth url.

So now you have a token that you can add an admin action for so the user can regenerate the token if it gets out into the wild.

clear as mud?

Comment: but wait, there's more. The action that generates the RSS (or returns cached if you are doing that) needs to clear the session at the end so a a persistent login session is not left behind.

Comment: and, depending on your app, you might want to add filters that prevent using the token to log into the rest of the app. ie. by urls other than the one used to pull RSS

Comment: forgot to add: to generate a token: call @user.ensure_authentication_token

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've for now settled for using HTTP Basic Auth, 'forcing' the user to use a client which supports it (many seem to do, nowadays). The token seems like a good solution except that my user base might not be the kind, which understands what a token actually is or/when/how they would re–generate it. I'll think a bit about it and get back to you. Cheers!

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since it seems to solve the problem at hand. I myself have used a different approach (comment above) and feel like I can't really recommend a token–based approach, though. Thanks for a detailed reply!